# How can I hide a field in the node add form but it unhide it on the node edit form?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm having a content type in that I want a field "Status" to be hidden in add content form page(I'm setting default value in that add content). Now I want that field to appear in edit form page of that node and user can able to edit it. I'm new to Drupal, so I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Show/Hide the status field using `hook_form_alter` like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form_state['node'];

  if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
    $form['YOUR_FIELD']['#access'] = FALSE; // Node is new!
  }
  else {
    $form['YOUR_FIELD']['#access'] = TRUE; // Node is not new!
  }
}
```

Then replace `YOUR_FIELD` with the field name of your status field.